# How to remove first and last values in a FOR EACH loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending values to input boxes from a Google Maps application. Each marker has a "routeTitle" attribute. I am able to get the "first point", "last point" and "all points" and appending them to input boxes.

However, how can I input all values except the first and last into an input box? In other words, all points between first and last.

```
for( var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ){
    $("#startpoint").val(markers[0].routeTitle); 
    $("#endpoint").val(markers[markers.length - 1].routeTitle); 
    $("#allpoints").val(markers[i].routeTitle); 
    $("#checkpoints").val( not sure); 
   };
```

Comment: `for( var i = 1; i < markers.length-1; i++ ){`

Comment: Thanks Rayon, I appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the first and last values outside the loop and then amend the loop structure to start from the second value and go until the second last value.

```
 $("#startpoint").val(markers[0].routeTitle); 
 $("#endpoint").val(markers[markers.length - 1].routeTitle); 

for( var i = 1; i < markers.length-2; i++ ){  
    $("#allpoints").val(markers[i].routeTitle); 
    $("#checkpoints").val( not sure); 
   };
```

Comment: Thanks! It only appends one value to the "checkpoints" input box though, how can I make it add all values? `for( var i = 1; i < markers.length-2; i++ ){$("#checkpoints").val(markers[i].routeTitle)};`

Comment: It varies depending on how many the user has selected. Currently it only shows one checkpoint in that textbox

Comment: hang on - you are using an id called checkpoints - if you have more than one element with the same id - then it will only fill the first one in. Each element needs to have a unique id. for example. #checkpoint1, #checkpoint2 etc  - same with #allpoints

Comment: and you might need to use "...markers.length-1.... " i might have made a mistake on that one.

Comment: each marker has an id which is why I am looping through them, I want to add the markers[].routeTitle for all checkpoints to a single checkpoint text box.

Comment: oh ok - i see the problem - what is happening on each iteration of the loop the $("#checkpoints").val( ); is being overwritten - in other words you are not adding to the content of the textbox - you are replacing it with the latest content. You need to do an append... or create a string  with each entry and at the end of the loop - add that to the checkbox val().

Comment: Oh I see! I'll try that out. Thank you so much!